# Why are timestamps stored in a uint (256 bit) when they would fit in a uint64?

Tags: evm, blocks, data-types, optimization

A (signed) 64 bit timestamp can store a date much larger than the age of the universe.

On many platforms this would be a micro-optimization, but in the context of Ethereum, we want to squeeze every drop of gas out, don't we?

Comment: My mistake in the title. A uint is 256 bits, not bytes.

Answer (score 2):

A storage slot is 256 bits, as are hashes, ETH amounts etc, so it's simpler to standardize on *returning* a 256-bit number.

However, if you need a timestamp in your contract you are under no obligation to store 256 bits: It's simple to cast it to a smaller size. This will often provide a gas saving if you're storing other small pieces of data at the same time.

Comment: Also the EVM is 256 bits machine operating data of size other from 256 bits requires extra steps.